# How to use sas macro variable into R code

Tags: r, sas

I need to use some sas macro variable in R as a part of script conversion from SAS to R.

Is there a function or package we have R to allow me to use code like:

```
%let Abc = xyz;
Y = &Abc;
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Don't do that in R, R is not made for macro-style programs. R is easier than SAS, has a totally different logic. Then, conversions from sas to R shouldn't be word-by-word. So use vectors, lists, data.frames, but don't do macro-language.

Comment: So in that case do i need to create a list which can store multiple values of same variable... Which i can use at various place as per calling function?

Comment: I don't know what is your goal so I can't tell :D that's like translating "like" in french, it depends on the context. There is no sas to R word-by-word translation. Why do you need macro-variables for ?

Comment: @ArnaudFeldmann SAS and R are different, easier is relative.

Comment: Code conversion is not done line by line, however, since R has variables you can just declare variables and use them anywhere. However, if you have a variable in a data set with the same name as a separate variable you need to be very careful with how you reference them to ensure it uses the right one.

Answer (score -1):

The functional equivalent is likely a variable:

```
   abc <- "xyz"
   y <- abc
   print(y)
```